# How are the numbers on the numerical pad of a keyboard encoded?

Tags: python, character-encoding

the following code pops-up a warning as soon as a "non-numeric" key it typed on the keyboard. The list 'keys' contains exceptions. Why does the warning pops-up when I type number from the numerical pad?
EDIT:'I fixed the problem adding the list ''KP_0', ..., 'KP_9''
However, are the numbers on the num pad coded differently under ubuntu? Do you suggest a more effective way to achieve that?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def validate_typed_char(event):
    key = event.keysym
    print(key)
    keys = ('Delete', 'BackSpace', 'Return', 'Insert', 'Tab', 'Caps_Lock', 'Shift_L', 
            'Shift_R', 'Control_L', 'Control_R', 'App', 'Win_R', 'Alt_R', 'Alt_L', 
            'Down', 'Up', 'Left', 'Right', 'End', 'Prior', 'Next', 'Num_Lock', 
            'period', 'comma', '', 'KP_0', 'KP_1', 'KP_2', 'KP_3', 'KP_4', 'KP_5', 
            'KP_6', 'KP_7', 'KP_8', 'KP_9')
    
    if key not in keys and not key.isnumeric():
        messagebox.showwarning(title='Title', message='Invalid character for - only numeric characters allowed!!')
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entryVar = tk.StringVar()
    tkEntry = tk.Entry(root)
    tkEntry.bind('<KeyRelease>', validate_typed_char)
    tkEntry.grid(row=0, column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ done. The code can be copied and run